# Maven looking for parent Jar instead of Pom in a multi-module project

Tags: maven

I have a parent module called Parent, and for the sake of simplicity just one submodule called A.

Parent module:

```
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>my.group.id</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent-artifact</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <modules>
        <module>A</module>
    </modules>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
</project>
```

Module A:

```
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>my.group.id</groupId>
        <artifactId>parent-artifact</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>A</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>my.group.id</groupId>
            <artifactId>parent-artifact</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

So when I try to do `mvn clean install` on the parent module, I get:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project A: Could not resolve dependencies for project my.group.id:A:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact my.group.id:parent-artifact:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT -> [Help 1]
```

Why is maven looking for the Jar instead of the pom file? I'm following Maven sample projects and I don't see anything that I'm missing here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You added the following dependency

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>my.group.id</groupId>
        <artifactId>parent-artifact</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
```

This dependency looks for the *jar* `parent-artifact` because `jar` is the standard packaging/type. I guess this dependency is just superfluous because `parent-artifact` is your parent POM and you already mentioned it in the parent element.

Comment: Thanks JF Meier. You're answer is right, my mistake was that I had source code on the parent module which I wanted to be shared among child modules. Hence, I added the dependency to the parent, otherwise I was getting compilation errors. The fix is to just move those codes on parent module to a new submodule instead and have module A depend on the new submodule instead. Thanks again for your answer.